# Should these questions be Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Considering https://android.stackexchange.com/privileges/community-wiki,

> **When should I make my answers Community Wiki?**
>
> 1. When you want to enhance the "wiki" aspect of your post, so that it can be
>      a continually evolving source of good
>      information through repeated editing.
> 2. When you feel your post would benefit from less concern about voting
>      affecting the reputation of those
>      participating in it

should the following questions be made CW?  I am specifically concerned about point #1, since these canonical questions will benefit from regular updates:

[How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone)
[I've rooted my phone.  Now what?  What do I gain from rooting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1/ive-rooted-my-phone-now-what)

If not, how are questions like [When will my phone get Android 2.3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread) different?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up.  I guess I forgot to wiki them once I became a mod :)

Comment: Yea they were fairly old questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, I think that's a good idea -- I've gone ahead and wiki-ed those posts.

There are also some fairly major changes coming to allow more editing by low rep and anon users, but the community wiki designator will always make editing easier.